# is it possible to compile separate apps for each language in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, localization, projects-and-solutions

So I created translations for `N` languages (using Qt linguist). I want to compile my app into `N` apps that differ with prefix like `_en_US` or `_fr_FR` embedding into each one translated strings. Also I want to keep one version of app which will automatically determine current platform language having all translation versions inside. How shall I change my `.pro` file to achieve such results?

Comment: The point of Qt's translation mechanism is so you don't need to do precisely what you're asking.

Comment: @Styne, I think the OP knows this. Why not try to answer the question as given?

Comment: @TonyK Because this kind of question screams 'bad design'. A sensible solution would be to make it obvious to the user how to change the language, then use Qt's built in mechanism. It just makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is much easier to embed all the translations and to decide at runtime
which one to load. Perhaps you can provide a command line switch or an option to
override the system locale. You do not even have to embed them in the executable,
you may ship them in a "translations" directory. To get the system locale at runtime
you can use [QLocale](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html) class:

```
Application application(argc, argv);

QString locale = QLocale::system().name();
QString translationsDir = ":/translations";

QTranslator appTranslator;
QTranslator qtTranslator;

appTranslator.load(locale, translationsDir);
qtTranslator .load("qt_" + locale,
                    QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));

application.installTranslator(& appTranslator);
application.installTranslator(& qtTranslator);
```

Anyway if you really want to do in your way you can rely on an environment variable `LANGUAGE_ID` to detect what language
to embed in your build, and then rebuild your project for each of the available
languages. It might take a lot of time, but maybe you can do that only for the
final build.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef EMBED_ONLY_ONE_LANGUAGE
    std::cout << "Embedded language is " << LANGUAGE_ID << std::endl;
#elif EMBED_ALL_LANGUAGES
    std::cout << "Embedded all languages" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "What???" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

And here is the .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .
TARGET = SomeName

CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += console

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp

# It seems that "equals" does not work with environment variables so we
# first read it in a local variable.
LANGUAGE_ID=$$(LANGUAGE_ID)

equals(LANGUAGE_ID,) {
    # No language id specified. Add the build instructions to embed all the
    # translations and to decide at runtime which one to load.
    message(No language id specified)

    # This adds a preprocessor variable so that the program knows that it has
    # every language.
    DEFINES *= EMBED_ALL_LANGUAGES
} else {
    # A language id was specified. Add the build instructions to embed only
    # the relative translation.
    message(Specified language id: $$LANGUAGE_ID)

    # This adds a preprocessor variable LANGUAGE_ID whose value is the language.
    DEFINES *= LANGUAGE_ID=\\\"$$LANGUAGE_ID\\\"

    # This adds a preprocessor variable so that the program knows that it has
    # only one language.
    DEFINES *= EMBED_ONLY_ONE_LANGUAGE

    # This renames the executable.
    TARGET=$${TARGET}_$$(LANGUAGE_ID)
}
```

It makes use of the undocumented [test function `equals`](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake#Test_functions). Note that if you
change the value of the environment variable `LANGUAGE_ID` you have to run qmake
again (possibly after having deleted the Makefiles).

A (perhaps better) alternative is to use CMake and specify the language id as
a CMake's command line variable:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(SomeName)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(SomeName ${SOURCES})

if(${LANGUAGE_ID} MATCHES "[a-z][a-z]_[A-Z][A-Z]")
    # A language id was specified. Add the build instructions to embed only
    # the relative translation.
    message("Embedding language ${LANGUAGE_ID}")

    # This adds a preprocessor variable LANGUAGE_ID whose value is the language.
    add_definitions("-DLANGUAGE_ID=\"${LANGUAGE_ID}\"")

    # This adds a preprocessor variable so that the program knows that it has
    # only one language.
    add_definitions("-DEMBED_ONLY_ONE_LANGUAGE")

    # This renames the executable.
    set_target_properties(SomeName PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "SomeName_${LANGUAGE_ID}")

else(${LANGUAGE_ID} MATCHES "[a-z][a-z]_[A-Z][A-Z]")
    # No language id specified. Add the build instructions to embed all the
    # translations and to decide at runtime which one to load.
    message("Not embedding any language")

    # This adds a preprocessor variable so that the program knows that it has
    # every language.
    add_definitions("-DEMBED_ALL_LANGUAGES")

endif(${LANGUAGE_ID} MATCHES "[a-z][a-z]_[A-Z][A-Z]")
```